# Find the Taylor polynomial of 2nd degree

Tags: calculus

f(x)= 1/2 ln((1+x)/1-x)), x(-1,1)

Better visualization: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTzn3.png
Need to find the Taylor polynomial P2(x) of 2nd degree to f at 0

What I've done for now. 
1/2 ln(1+x)/1-x) = 1/2(ln(1+x)-ln(1-x)

And to find the Taylor series i need to set f(0). (correct me if I am doing anything wrong. Which in this case would be 0, as ln(1)=0. 
What is the next move?

Comment: You just need to use the Taylor expansions of $\ln(1+x)$ and $\ln (1-x)$, which are standard formulæ.

Comment: With your parenthesing, the function is $1/2\ln(1)$ !

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $f'(x)=\left(\dfrac{\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)}2\right)'=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac1{1+x}+\dfrac1{1-x}\right)=\dfrac1{1-x^2}=1+x^2+x^4+\cdots$

Then as $f(0)=0$, by integration

$$f(x)=x+\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^5}5+\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor polynomial at zero is given by: $T_2f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2$.

So the next move is to find the first and second derivative of $f$, evaluate it at $0$ and substitute them in the previous expression.

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{1-x})$, so that at zero $f'(0)=1$. I let you doing the computation of the second derivative.

Comment: Sorry, why the downvote? I would like to correct myself if I have wrote something wrong.

Comment: So, f′'(x) = 1/2 ( 1/(1-x)^2 - 1/(x+1)^2. Anf if I set f''(0) i would get f''(0)= 1/2

Comment: why? $\ln(x)'=\frac{1}{x}$. Where is your logarithm disappearing?

Comment: There is no need to evaluate the second derivative.

Comment: And also the computation is false: $f''(x)=\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^2})$ which is zero is equal to $0$, as @Yves Daoust explained.

Answer (score 0):

The function is odd (substitute $x\leftrightarrow-x$) so that the $P_2$ approximation is simply $f'(0)\,x$ (no terms of even degree). And it is a simple matter to find $f'(0)=1$.

Comment: 1/2(1/(1+x) - (1/1-x))

plugging in at 0 we get 1

so the taylor series of degree 2 is

T_2(x) =x      So the final answere here is that T_2(x) =x  ?

Comment: @MatrhWonder00: you can check my other answer for a confirm.